# Idiomatic way to define multiple backends in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I want to write code with a multiple user interface backends (textual and graphical for instance), so they are easy to switch. My approach is using CLOS:

```
(defgeneric draw-user-interface (argument ui)
  (:documentation "Present the user interface")
  (:method (argument (ui (eql :tui)))
    (format t "Textual user interface! (~A)" argument))
  (:method (argument (ui (eql :gui)))
    (format t "Graphical user interface! (~A)" argument)))
```

This approach seems OK at a first glance, but it has a few cons. To simplify calls, I define parameter *ui-type* which will be used in each function call, to simplify switching the backend, but it causes a problem when using higher order functions:

```
(defparameter *ui-type* :tui
  "Preferred user interface type")

(draw-user-interface 3 *ui-type*)

;;; I can't use the following due to the `ui' argument:
;(mapcar #'draw-user-interface '(1 2 3))

;;; Instead I have to write this
(mapcar #'(lambda (arg)
            (draw-user-interface arg *ui-type*))
        '(1 2 3))

;; or this
(mapcar #'draw-user-interface
        '(1 2 3)
        (make-list 3 :initial-element *ui-type*))

;; The another approach would be defining a function
(defun draw-user-interface* (argument)
  (draw-user-interface argument *ui-type*))

;; and calling mapcar
(mapcar #'draw-user-interface* '(1 2 3))
```

If such approach is taken, we could name the generic function %draw-user-interface and the wrapper function just draw-user-interface.

Is it valid approach or there is something more straightforward? Question is about providing a different backends for the same functionality, not necessarily the user interface.

The another use case might be a situation, when I have many implementations of the same algorithm (optimized for speed, memory consumption etc.) and I want to switch them in a clean way preserving the interface and the argument types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement other answers, there are two libraries for this use case. Both are inspired in the [Magritte Meta Model](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~scg/Archive/Papers/Reng07aMagritte.pdf), you should check it out.

One is [descriptions](https://github.com/mmontone/descriptions) which allows you to define different 'views' of an object. It doesn't use CLOS but [Sheeple](https://github.com/zkat/sheeple), a prototype-based object system for CL. An earlier approach is [MAO](https://github.com/mmontone/cl-mao), which is CLOS based. It adds 3 additional slots to the standard slot object. attribute-label, attribute-function, and attribute-value. The function in attribute-function a transforms the slot-value into the final representation, if function is nil the value in attribute-value is used as is. And label is a description of the value, similar to labels in html5 forms.

Answer (score 5):

I would implement the backends as separate classes, instead of passing a keyword around, since that would allow me to hook various state into an object and keep that around.

I'd probably (otherwise) use the generic function design you've been alluding to.

Comment: Good argument regarding the class instead of a symbol (@jkiiski proposed the same). It doesn't solve the HO function problem though. Thanks for the opinion. I'm marking this answer as "accepted".

Comment: @DanielKochmański There's no real HO function problem, though.  The function you're looking at really has two arguments (the backend and the input).  `(mapcar (lambda (input) (do-stuff backend input)) inputs)` is the standard way to do that.  You could also define a currying function, so that you could do:  `(mapcar (curry #'do-stuff backend) inputs)`, but while that saves some typing, it's less idiomatic (since readers have to find out what your `curry` does).

Answer (score 5):

**Common Lisp Interface Manager and multiple backends**

An example for a UI layer in CLOS supporting multiple backends is CLIM, the Common Lisp Interface Manager. **You could study its software design.** See the links below. See for example the *protocols* around classes like *port* (a connection to a display service), *medium* (where drawing happens, a protocol class that corresponds to the output state for some kind of sheet), *sheet* (a surface for painting and input, roughly similar to hierarchical windows), *graft* (a sheet which stands in for a host window), ... In an application one opens a port (for example to a specific window system like X11/Motif) and the rest of the application should be running mostly unchanged. The architecture of CLIM maps all its services then to a specific CLIM backend, which provides the interface to X11/Motif (or whatever port you would be using).

For example the function `draw-line` would be drawing to *sheets*, *streams* and *mediums*. The *generic function* `medium-draw-line*` would then implement various versions of drawing lines to one or more *medium* subclasses.

In general this was not very successful, because a portable user interface layer brings complexity and needs a lot of work to develop and maintain. In the mid 90s the market for Lisp applications was small (see the AI Winter), CLIM wasn't good enough and the implementation was closed source and or proprietary. Later an open source / free implementation called McCLIM was developed which created working software - but eventually developers/users lost interest.

**A bit of history**

In former times Symbolics developed a user interface system called 'Dynamic Windows'. It was released in 1986. It ran in the Symbolics operating system and could draw to its native OS/Hardware combination and X11. Starting in around 1988 a portable CLOS-based version was developed. The first available versions (especially version 1.0 in 1991) was available on several platforms: Genera, X11, Mac and Windows. Later a new version was developed (version 2.0) which again ran on various systems, but included a complex object-oriented layer which provided a more explicit backend layer called Silica. This backend layer did not only support things like portable drawing, but also parts of an abstract window system. The more ambitious parts, like support for adaption in look and feel (sliders, window styles, scrollbars, menus, dialog elements, ...) were not fully worked out, but were at least available as a first generation version.

**Pointers**

[A Guided Tour of CLIM, Common Lisp Interface Manager](http://clemens.endorphin.org/a-guided-tour-of-CLIM-2006.pdf) (PDF)

Silica : [Implementation Reflection in Silica](http://extras.springer.com/2000/978-3-540-67660-7/papers/0512/05120251.pdf) (PDF)

The Spec (which includes Silica): [Common Lisp Interface Manager 2.0 Specification](http://bauhh.dyndns.org:8000/clim-spec/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

By "backend" you mean frontend, right? As in, the part that the user interacts with, rather than the part that handles the application logic?

The cleanest option would be to divide your program into a library (which provides all the logic and features of the program without any UI code) and two completely separate UI programs that don't implement any features themselves, but rather just use the library. You can of course have a wrapper that chooses which interface to run, if necessary. You should keep each component in their own system.

**Edit:** When you want to switch between different algorithms, the best option is probably simply to define the interface as a class, and all the different algorithms as subclasses.

```
(defclass backend () ())
(defgeneric do-something (backend x y))

(defclass fast-backend (backend) ())
(defmethod do-something ((backend fast-backend) x y)
  (format t "Using fast backend with arguments ~a, ~a.~%" x y))

(defclass low-mem-backend (backend) ())
(defmethod do-something ((backend low-mem-backend) x y)
  (format t "Using memory efficient backend with arguments ~a, ~a.~%" x y))

(defun main (x y)
  (let ((backends (list (make-instance 'fast-backend)
                        (make-instance 'low-mem-backend))))
    (dolist (b backends)
      (do-something b x y))))
```

**Another edit:** If you need to be able to use functions like `mapcar`, you might want to have a global variable containing the current backend. Then define a wrapper function that uses the global.

```
(defparameter *backend* (make-instance 'fast-backend))
(defun foobar (x y)
  (do-something *backend* x y))

(defun main (x y)
  (foobar x y)
  (let ((*backend* (make-instance 'low-mem-backend)))
    (foobar x y))
  (foobar x y))
```

Comment: By "backend" I mean "backend" – we may have three implementations of the same algorithm (let's call it XXX123), each having it's own characteristics (one optimized for speed, the other one for memory consumption, and the third one is some compromise between both). I want to switch the implementations in a clean way preserving the same interface and the argument types.

Comment: Your post is quite confusing in that regard. Maybe you should leave out all that about drawing user interfaces, and just focus on the different algorithms. Having several UIs is pretty different problem.

Comment: What contitutes a "backend" or a "frontend" is purely a matter of what viewpoint you have. For a program drawing graphics, the logical backend (the thing you do things to) is the thing that displays the UI to the user.

Comment: UI is just an example and I believe that I explained in detail what I want to achieve and what solution came to my mind. I have also explicitly said, that it's more general question. After noticing you got confused I've added an another example distinct from the UI one (which I believe is very valid too).

Comment: Regarding the answer, your solution is similar to the first approach (without the wrapper function), but instead of a symbol you provide some class (what gives me ability to pass some state, as @Vatine pointed on the second answer). Note, that I would have to change each (do-something b x y) argument b, to change the behaviour (or use some global object *my-b*). Either way I'll have the same problems with the higher order functions I've listed (what isn't a big deal, I'm just wondering if there is commonly agreed approach to such things).

Comment: @Vatine I have to disagree with that. In an application that draws graphics, the backend would still be the library that handles the drawing (by providing functions like `(draw-rectangle surface x y w h)`). The frontend could be a GUI that reads input from the mouse, or a command line interface for scripts to use. Those two frontends are very unlikely to share any code, and as such should be implemented in separate systems using the shared backend library.

Comment: @jkiiski And the thing in X11 that has the screen, keyboard and mouse attached is the server or the client? What is a backend and what is a frontend is purely a matter of in which direction you look. For X11 and teh protoc designers, the answer is "the server" (the program wanting to draw on the screen, or read from the keyboard, is the client).

Comment: @jkiiski regarding the second edit – that's a wrapper function I've proposed in a question asking, if it's idiomatic

Comment: @Vatine When you have two programs communicating with each other, they probably both have a backend and a frontend, so in that sense you're right. However, when you have a user directly interacting with a program, I'd say the backend is the part that implements the features, and frontend is the part that translates user input to function calls and return values to pixels on the screen. Daniel Koghmanski: True. I added it to show that IMO it's the best solution.

Comment: In a portable UIMS, the frontend is the code which provides the portable API and services. For example the abstract facilities for drawing lines given various parameters (color, thickness, line styles, ...). There will be a window system independent way to specify those. The backend is the specific mapping to the real window system. This will interface to the GUI specific code (GTK+, Cocoa, ...) which eventually draws the lines to pixels on the screen then. Here window specific parameters are used.